# How to use sprintf/snprintf with double pointer char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, struct

The code below 'should' store arrays of strings in the varible `name` which **needs** to be under `struct data`. Suppose that the number of array elements are determined at the runtime, and in the example code below they are defined with `DYNAMIC_ELEMENTS`. The strings are formated using `sprintf`.

```
#define DYNAMIC_ELEMENTS 10

struct data {
    char **name;
};

int main()
{
 struct data *data = calloc(1, sizeof(*data));
 data->name = calloc(DYNAMIC_ELEMENTS, sizeof(data->name[0]));

 for (int i = 0; i <= DYNAMIC_ELEMENTS; i++) {
     sprintf(data->name[i], "Name %u", i + 1);
     printf("%s\n", data->name[i]);
 }
  return 0;
}
```

As I run this code, I get a segfault. The error is coming from the line

`sprintf(data->name[i], "Name %u", i + 1);`

Any idea whats going wrong here?

Update: The code complies if I take the approach below (but I would like to avoid this):

```
//...
char buf[127];
sprintf(buf, "Name %u", i + 1);     
data->name[i] = strdup(buf);
//...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
i <= DYNAMIC_ELEMENTS
```

is accessing past the bounds of the memory that you've allocated. You should use:

```
i < DYNAMIC_ELEMENTS
```

You should also allocate memory for each individual string:

```
data->name[i] = calloc(1, snprintf(NULL, 0, "Name %u", i + 1));
```

Full example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DYNAMIC_ELEMENTS; i++) {
    data->name[i] = calloc(1, snprintf(NULL, 0, "Name %u", i + 1));
    sprintf(data->name[i], "Name %u", i + 1);
    printf("%s\n", data->name[i]);
}
```

The reason that this works:

```
//...
char buf[127];
sprintf(buf, "Name %u", i + 1);     
data->name[i] = strdup(buf);
//...
```

is because you're allocating memory with `strdup` and assigning it to `data->name[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
 struct data *data = calloc(1, sizeof(*data)); 
 data->name = calloc(DYNAMIC_ELEMENTS, sizeof(data->name[0]));

 for (int i = 0; i < DYNAMIC_ELEMENTS; i++) { /* correctly count till 10 */
     data->name[i] = calloc(256, sizeof(data->name[0][0])); /* allocate memory before copying to it */
     ...
```

Comment: `calloc(256, sizeof(data->name[0][0]));` limits the size of the string to 255 bytes. What if this were pages of a book or extremely large numbers?

Comment: @JL2210, `%u` means decimal representation of `unsigned int` ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf ). Which is most probably 4 bytes ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types ), and not more than 8 bytes, so fits into 256 characters. Of course this is a toy example, better to measure before allocation.

Comment: "Which is most probably 4 bytes ...  and not more than 8 bytes" is unclear.  As a 32-bit `unsigned` a decimal representation would need 11 byes to store `"4294967295"` - which also fits in 256 bytes - yes quite excessive.